# how to use $editFormAction in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I have created a form that has a subit button which will submit the for to a database, and a email button which will run a .cgi script to process the mail.  Im having trouble getting the submit button to work.
here is the form buttons

```
<FORM name="drop_list"  method="POST" >
<input name="emailForm" type="button" id="emailForm" onClick="sendFormEmail()" value="Email">
<input name="add_patient" type="button" id="add_patient" onClick="addPatient()" value="Add Patient">
</FORM>
```

And here is my javascript

```
function sendFormEmail() //email form
    {
        alert ("Email, this is disabled atm");
        document.drop_list.action = "html_form_send.php"
        document.drop_list.submit();             // Submit the page
        return true;
    }

function addPatient() //Post form to data base
    {
    alert ("Post to database");
    document.drop_list.action = <?php echo $editFormAction; ?>;
    document.drop_list.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
    }
```

The sendFormEmail() works fine, but when I try to use addPatient(). The form will not submit and something in the  document.drop_list.action = ; line completely breaks the java script.

Thanks in advance for your help.

-Gregg

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown the value of `$editFormAction`, but I'll bet it doesn't have quotes around it. So you need to write:

```
document.drop_list.action = "<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>";
```

If you checked in the Javascript console, you should have seen an error message about an undefined variable or undefined not having a `php` method. And then if you looked at the JS source, you would have noticed that the script name doesn't have quotes around it, like it does in `sendFormEmail`.